# why null pointer exception does not provide the expression that is null?

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, error-logging

Unless, there is a code line like, `throw new NullPointerException();` null pointers usually occur when an expression that turns out to be `null` is operated upon. So, my question is, why does the message for the null pointer not contain the expression which is returning null?

Comment: Could you post some example to illustrate what you're trying to ask? Stack trace does provide the line number where the exception happens.

Comment: In the face of optimizations, etc, all that is usually known at runtime is "this thing that was meant to be a reference is actually `null`". That reference may have been computed elsewhere, at any point in the past.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know for sure, but I imagine that the reason is that there could be major performance issues if the JVM had to be able to report the precise expression that threw the exception.

At the very least, it would require changes to the class file format to include (really) fine grained source code position information ... finer grained than line numbers.

Anyway, the question is moot ... 'cos it doesn't.

Comment: Just because java is a programming language, I would not stop questioning its implementation!

Comment: @MozenRath - Well if you want a real answer, you are asking the wrong people.  Ask the Java team.  OTOH, if you are actually "questioning" Java (i.e. criticising it) then SO is not an appropriate place to do that; see the FAQ.

Answer (score 4):

`NullPointerException` occurs when you try to dereference a `null`, not when you just create or have one. Stack trace contains the line, and that's as good as it gets, and JVM does not really know where the `null` came from, it does not keep track of such things when it tries to churn through the bytecode as fast as possible.

---

If you have trouble debugging such situations, you can always split expression and use temp variable:

```
String tmp = myObj.getSomething();
String result = tmp.substring(1);
```

If 1st line above throws NullPointerException (with stack trace showing it came from that line, not from inside `myObj.getSomething()`), you know myObj was null. If 2nd line throws NullPointerException, you know `tmp` was null, ie `myObj.getSomething()` returned null. If you then notice that `myObj.getSomething()` may in fact return null in normal situation, you can then add `if (tmp != null) { ... } else { ... }` kind of code there.